# Regex for Email Address validation

Tags: c#, regex, email-validation

I am trying to validate email addresses. Currently I'm using the following  regex to validate email addresses which works perfectly fine. But I now want to tweek it and allow only `min` 2 and `max` 40 characters for the domain-part of the email address i.e after the `@` symbol. I tried setting the range but I guess it wont work like this. Where am I going wrong?

The Regex:

```
^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,})$
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Answer (score 0):

Validating email addresses is non-trivial, and your regex as it is rejects perfectly good email addresses such as `test+1234@localhost`. If you need to do it yourself, have a look at [RFC 822 §6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-6).

However, in C#, there is a class `MailAddress` with a constructor accepting a string argument. You can attempt to construct a `MailAddress addr = new MailAddress(emailString)`, and see whether it throws a `FormatException`. As a benefit, the `MailAddress` object has many useful methods for working with email addresses.

EDIT: My apologies, I missed that you were trying to limit the host length. If you create the `MailAddress` as above, then `addr.Host` will contain the hostname part, and you can check its length.